# ParallelStream toArray of higher size Java8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to create an array with higher size from a parallel stream

```
myList.parallelStream().map((listElm) -> {
            return someObjectMorpher(listElm);}).toArray(size -> new SomeObject[size+4]);
```

1. Is it guaranteed that the last 4 elements of the array will always be null?
   Which means toArray will always populate at first indices of the Array.
2. Is there a possibility of having toArray populate an already created array

   ```
   SomeObjet [] arr = new SomeObject[myList.size() + 4];
   arr[0] = new SomeObject(x);
   myList.parallelStream()
       .map((listElm) -> { return someObjectMorpher(listElm);})
       .toArray(**///use arr** );
   ```

Comment: Have you tried executing the code?

Comment: Are you trying to put the values in the array starting from a certain offset? You might be better off using a List and adding elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it guaranteed that the last 4 elements of the array will always be null?

Essentially, no.  The last four elements of the array will retain their previous value.  If the value happened to be `null`, then they will remain `null`.  For example:

```
Integer[] array = Stream.of(7, 8).parallel().toArray(i -> new Integer[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6});

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Output:

```
[7, 8, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

> Is there a possibility of having toArray populate an already created array

Yes, see above, as well as another example:

```
Integer[] array = new Integer[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

Integer[] newArray = Stream.of(7, 8).parallel().toArray(i -> array);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray));
```

Output:

```
[7, 8, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

**Note**: Attempting this with sequential streams will throw an `IllegalStateException` if the length of the array differs from the size of the stream.

Comment: the thing that it breaks in a non-parallel way is actually correct and you simply got lucky that it does not break in parallel way. Also, the fact that elements are put into the front of the array is again implementation dependent, I highly doubt this is specified somewhere (I searched... ). the only correct way to do this IMO is to build a custom collector

Comment: I originally answered this without using a parallel stream and it had thrown an exception.  When I tried it in parallel, I was surprised to see that it worked.  I wonder why that occurs.

Comment: Do *never* return an existing array from that function. [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-) clearly says “*using the provided generator function to allocate the returned array, as well as any additional arrays that might be required for a partitioned execution or for resizing*”. In other words, the function may get evaluated multiple times in order to provide distinct array instances. Imagine what could happen if they are actually the same array perhaps even accessed by different threads…

Answer (score 2):

**Update**
It seems based on this question:
[Why can I collect a parallel stream to an arbitrarily large array but not a sequential stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49760818/why-can-i-collect-a-parallel-stream-to-an-arbitrarily-large-array-but-not-a-sequ)

That

```
toArray(size -> new Integer[size + 4])
```

Is breaking the contract of the generator https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-

> generator - a function which produces a new array of the desired type and the provided length

So even though the assertions below pass, **the code below should not be used**.

**Original response**

> Is it guaranteed that the last 4 elements of the array will always be null? Which means toArray will always populate at first indices of the Array.

This does work if you provide a generator function to allocate a new array of your desired size.

```
    Integer[] result = Arrays.asList(3,4,5).parallelStream().map(i -> i + 1).toArray(size -> new Integer[size + 4]);
    assert(result.length == 7);
    assert(result[3] == null);
    assert(result[4] == null);
    assert(result[5] == null);
    assert(result[6] == null);
```

All of these assertions pass.

Comment: if something passes *some* tests, it does not make it a rule. the java-doc would, but not such is present

Comment: It must be guarenteed that

    new Integer[size + 4] 

will always return an array of the indicated size. We should be able to count on that.

Comment: Also, since array holds type Integer (a reference to an object) we are guaranteed that its values will be initialized to null as the result of new Integer[size + 4]

Comment: that was not the point, do you see any guarantees in the doc that says that elements are going to be put in the front of the array?

Comment: No.  That's true it does not.

Comment: that might be always so, it would not be the first time when the doc omits something, but someone like Stuart Marks or Brian Goetz would be needed here