# Why can I collect a parallel stream to an arbitrarily large array but not a sequential stream?

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

From answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49760006/7294647), I ran into a peculiar feature.  The following code works as I assumed it would (the first two values within the existing array would be overridden):

```
Integer[] newArray = Stream.of(7, 8)
                           .parallel()
                           .toArray(i -> new Integer[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6});

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray));
```

Output:

```
[7, 8, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

However, attempting this with a sequential stream throws an `IllegalStateException`:

```
Integer[] newArray = Stream.of(7, 8)
                           .toArray(i -> new Integer[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6});

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray));
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Begin size 2 is not equal to fixed size 6
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Nodes$FixedNodeBuilder.begin(Nodes.java:1222)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:483)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:550)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluateToArrayNode(AbstractPipeline.java:260)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:517)
    at test/test.Test.main(Test.java:30)
```

I'm curious as to why the sequential stream does not overwrite elements of the array as the parallel stream does.  I searched around a bit and was not able to find documentation regarding this, but I assume it exists somewhere.

Comment: I am sure Holger will shed some light here as to why this is so, going into the woods of stream api internals, most probably this will happen tomorrow

Comment: @Eugene I don't think that it is worth digging deeper than to the fact that both executions run through different code (using `filter` or any other op making it unsized let it run to another different code). Throwing on contract violations is not a guaranteed behavior.

Comment: @Holger thank you for confirming this...

Comment: @Holger any thoughts around, why would the API note and the implementation for the `Collection#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction)` and `Stream#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction)` differ? e.g. `var collectionToArray = list.toArray(value -> new Integer[]{0});` would succeed while  `var streamToArray = list.stream().toArray(value -> new Integer[]{0});` would fail with a similar error as stated by the OP. I couldn't really convince myself on the contradictory behaviour of the APIs. (shouldn't the consistency matter while designing?)

Comment: @Naman `Stream.toArray(IntFunction)` is a genuine Stream operation. In contrast, `Collection.toArray(IntFunction)` has been added in JDK 11, so the `default` implementation had to work atop the existing interface methods, so it’s just implemented as `return toArray(generator.apply(0));` and the contract of the method it delegates to, is to accept an array of arbitrary size, creating and returning a new one if it is too small.

Comment: @Holger the implementation was kind of clear to me, the introduction of API on an existing interface, used as a bridge and hence making use of the existing method. I believe the underlying question that I might have failed to pose was that why do we need such strict validationas(begin size, accept size, end size, etc) within streams converted to an array and not be as lenient as we are while performing a collection to an array? Is it to deal with concurrency?

Comment: @Naman “being lenient” is not a good thing, it’s a source of errors. But it’s not possible to change the contract of `toArray(A[])`. For `Collection.toArray(IntFunction)` that is only used for creating the zero-sized array and typically used with `Type[]::new`, such a check would not very useful. In contrast, the `Stream.toArray` may use the `IntFunction` to create the final result array (when the size is known in advance).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `generator` function is [required](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-) to produce "a new array of the desired type **and the provided length**." If you don't comply with the spec, behavior is undefined.

Comment: @user7 it falls under "undefined", it *happens* to work, might not in the next build

Comment: should the answer read Javadoc instead of spec? I was slightly puzzled with that term in use to consider that the API spec somewhere recommended that. (or does it really?)

Comment: @Naman I just meant the method contract as specified by the Javadoc.

Comment: @Naman I’d say [JLS §1.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-1.html#jls-1.4) makes the API documentation a kind of specification.